# PHP Image Processing

Tags: php, mysql, image, image-processing, directory

So I have created a small script that allows a user to upload multiple images of their car. I then process these images and store the file path in a database, and create a folder to store the images in, inside my 'vehicleImages' folder. I keep running into a problem though, so as you can see I check to see if the folder exists and if it doesn't I create one. Then the images get processed and in theory should be stored inside that folder.

The problem i'm running into is, it creates the folder like it should e.g. XX00VVV. But instead of storing the images inside 'vehcileImages/XX00VVV' it stores the images inside 'vehicleImages' not inside the correct folder. I've checked the server and the folder 'XX00VVV' is definetly being created but for some reason the images aren't being stored inside. I think it's where I change the target path but I can't figure out why. Can someone give me a few pointers/hints as to where I've gone wrong please?

```
    $imagePath = "../../images/vehicleImages/".$vehicleReg;
$fileName = $vehicleReg; 
if (!file_exists($imagePath)) {
    mkdir($imagePath, 0777, true);
}

//Image Upload Section

$j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

    $target_path = $imagePath; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) { //loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png"); //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i])); //explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path.md5(uniqid()).
        ".".$ext[count($ext) - 1]; //set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1; //increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
            && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) { //if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j.
                ').<span id="noerror">Image Uploaded Successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else { //if file was not moved.
                echo $j.
                ').<span id="error">Please Try Again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else { //if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j.
            ').<span id="error">***Invalid File Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }

//End Image Upload Section
```

[Image of Website Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa2RK.png)

Comment: please can you put a screenshot of image directories

Comment: @abdoEl-zahaby I've edited the question to have an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem is in first line in your code `$imagePath`

```
$imagePath = "../../images/vehicleImages/".$vehicleReg;
```

try to add `."/"` to the end of line
like this:

```
$imagePath = "../../images/vehicleImages/".$vehicleReg."/";
```

---

the explain of the solution is:

when you didn't add `/` in the end of path, you make it merged with filename , eg `XX00VVVfilenam.png`

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, thanks so much for your help